# Angularjy - Is Index.html the default page always?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to angular,Does Index.html file should be the default page or starting page always ? I have never seen a tutorial or any example that has any other default page name other than index.html. Appreciate the help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index

Comment: generally use `index` so file name doesn't need to be displayed. Can be any file though and any file extension that server can deliver as html

Comment: Thanks! If you can write it as answer, will mark it as answer and close the thread.